# Using fetch in while loop throws warning midway through returning and processing results

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am running the following query and it functions as desired most of the time, however occasionally it will loop through a few times and then throw this warning:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::fetch(): Couldn't fetch mysqli_stmt in...
```

I believe it is results related but at this point I am at a loss.

```
$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;

$sql = "SELECT id, join_id, bus_name, first_name, last_name, address, city, state,
       zip, phone, fax, email, wsaddr FROM auctioneer";

$bystate = " ORDER BY state ".$limit;//by state

$sortedLastSQL = " ORDER BY last_name ".$limit;// sort by last_name

$alphbeticalSql = " WHERE bus_name LIKE '".$order."%' ".$limit; //sort by letter

$sortOrderStSql = " WHERE state LIKE '".$order."%' ORDER BY state ASC ".$limit;

$sortOrderLnSql = " WHERE last_name LIKE '".$order."%' ORDER BY last_name,
first_name ASC ".$limit;

if(empty($_GET['sort']) && empty($_GET['order'])){
    $sql = $sql.' '.$limit;
}
if(!empty($_GET['order']) && empty($_GET['sort'])){
    $sql = $sql.$alphbeticalSql;
}
if(!empty($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort'] === 'state' && empty($_GET['order'])){
    $sql = $sql.$bystate;
}
if(!empty($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort'] === 'last_name' && empty($_GET['order'])){
    $sql = $sql.$sortedLastSQL;
}
if(!empty($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort'] === 'state' && !empty($_GET['order'])
&& $_GET['order'] = range('A','Z')){
    $sql = $sql.$sortOrderStSql;
}
if(!empty($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort'] === 'last_name' && !empty($_GET['order'])
&& $_GET['order'] = range('A','Z')){
    $sql = $sql.$sortOrderLnSql;
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $join_id, $bus_name, $first_name, $last_name,
      $address, $city, $state, $zip, $phone, $fax, $email,$wsaddr);

while($stmt->fetch()){
    //do a ton of stuff here
}
```

**NOTE:** This is just a raw query at this point no security has been put in place for debugging purposes.

Comment: What's your code? this isn't supposed to happen when you do something like `while ( $row =  ..fetch() ) {}`.

Comment: That is almost exactly what I have, my exact code is `while($stmt->fetch())` I am digging to figure it out now and I am leaning towards there being a duplicate record. But I need to dig a little more to be sure.

Comment: Perhaps you do an extra fetch before (or after) the loop.

Comment: Well it isn't a duplicate thing and I have a couple of other fetches but in trouble shooting I have changed them from $stmt to something unique...  I  have ruled out it just being because of a single result being returned by working off a much bigger db, I don't have a clue what is causing it but my db looks odd when I order it in the same as the query... Could it be somethign with the db?

Comment: I doubt it. Could you post some code?

Comment: Posted code and rewrote the question as it is not single results related, I can now reproduce the error on a much larger db that garuntees no singular results.

Answer (score 0):

SO the problem wasn't in the larger piece of code found above, it was contained in the while loop itself.

I had the following:

```
while($stmt->fetch()){ 
    if($join_id != 0){
        $sql3 = "SELECT count(*) FROM auctions WHERE join_id = ?";
        $st = $conn->prepare($sql3);
        $st->bind_param("i", $join_id);
        $st->execute();

        $st->store_result();
        $st->bind_result($l);

        $st->fetch();
        $st->close();
    }
}
```

by adding `else { $l = 0; }` to the if statement the problem dissappeared.

And this is why I HATE prepared statements because it is always a wild goose chase!